# FlexSlider - reset slideshowSpeed when jumping to slide

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have a website where I'm utilizing flex Slider.  I have a navigation where the user can jump to slides.

It is a continuous carousel slide show.  Right now I have slideshowSpeed set to 6000 milliseconds.

The problem is this: when the user jumps to a new slide, the slideshowSpeed is not reset.
For instance: we're on slide one, 2000 milliseconds elapse and the user clicks to slide 3.  Now there are only 4000 milliseconds remaining on slide 3.  I would like to reset the timer to  begin the 6000 millisecond count again.

Anyone have a good idea on how to do this?  maybe it isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where the client could determine how long each slide appears before moving on. I found that changing slider.slideshowSpeed would indeed change the slideshowSpeed property in the slider but it would have no affect.

On looking at the non-min version of the flexSlider code I found that all the properties you set when you initialise the slider are put into an object called vars, so to change the time I needed to pause the slider, change the vars property for slideshowSpeed then resume the slider:

//pause the slider

.slider.pause();

// change any variables in the slider

slider.vars.slideshowSpeed = parseInt(slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide).attr("intermission")) * 1000;

//restart the slider

slider.resume();

where slider.resume() initialises the animation again.

In the example above I have an attribute on the li called "intermission" that has a number in it that determines the new speed of the slide, x1000 so it is in ms.

Regarding your issue, I would guess that if you pause the slider then resume it again, the slider timing should reset.

slider.pause();

slider.resume();

Give it a go - I hope it works for you.

Perhaps some property Getters and Setters would be useful in FlexSlider but I guess not having them keeps the filesize to a minimum when there is a workaround (even if undocumented) available.

Cheers,
Jonathan